# Problem understanding a specific modular arithmetic (10x ≡ 6mod 7 )

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Here is my first logical steps to solve **10x ≡ 6mod7**
 1. 20mod7 ≡ 6mod7, which evaluate to 6 
 2. 10 $\times$ 2 = 20 
 3. Therefore, multiply both sides of congruence by 2.

After these steps I have: **20x ≡ 12mod7** 
 My questions is: how could this evaluate to **x=2**. What are the next steps from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\ 10\equiv 3\,$ so it's just $\,3x\equiv 6\,$ so $\,x\equiv\, \ldots \ \ $

Comment: I got your hint and appreciate it. But e.g.<b>  $\ 6x\equiv7mod599$ </b> would be 6 ≡ 6 so its 6x ≡ 6, so x ≡ 1 ?

Comment: @BakrAlashwal Your last comment is pretty confusing. First, what does $\;6x\equiv7\pmod{599}\;$ have to do with $\;6x\equiv6\;$ ? The comment above tells you that since $\;10\equiv3\pmod 7\;$ , then your equation is the same as $\;3x=6\pmod 7\;$ , and *then* you can divide by three both sides (since $\;3\;$ is invertible modulo $\;7\;$ ...) and get $\;x=2\pmod7\;$, which you can check again that is indeed a solution to the equation in its original setting.

Answer (score 0):

So we have $20x \equiv 12 \ (mod\ 7)$.
We can reduce this to $$6x \equiv 5 \ (mod\ 7)\ (*)$$
Note that $gcd(6, 7)=1$ and $1|5$, so a solution does exist.
Here's one way you can solve this:

Mod the left-hand side by $7$: $6x \equiv 5 \ (mod\ 7) \Rightarrow -x \equiv 5\ (mod\ 7)$.

Multiply by $-1$: $$(-1)(-x) \equiv (-1)5\ (mod\ 7) \Rightarrow x \equiv -5 \equiv 2\ (mod\ 7). $$

Thus, $x \equiv 2\ (mod\ 7)$.

Check: $10x \equiv 6\ (mod\ 7) \Rightarrow 10(2) =20 \equiv 6\ (mod\ 7)$. It works!